# Видео по ширине экрана. Баг при загрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, видео

В шапке стоит видео, которое я через JS подгружаю и подгоняю под размер экрана. Но при первой загрузке страницы видео не растягивается по ширине экрана. Только если ресайзнуть окно. Что делать?

Тестируемое разрешение экрана 1366x768. Вот [сам сайт](https://mine.by) и код:

```
var scWidth;
var scHeight;

function window_resize() {
    scWidth = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
    scHeight = (window.innerHeight > 0) ? window.innerHeight : screen.height;
    $('.scroll_bottom').css('display', (scHeight < scWidth ? 'block' : 'none'));

    var mainmenu = $('.mainmenu');
    var mainvideo = $('#mainvideo');
    if (scWidth > 767) {
        if (mainvideo.length < 1) {
            mainmenu.prepend('<video muted autoplay loop class="video" id="mainvideo"><source src="/assets/video/bg.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>');
            mainvideo = $('#mainvideo');
        }

        mainvideo.attr('style', '');
        if (mainvideo.height() < mainmenu.height()) {
            // Делаем по всей высоте
            scale = mainmenu.height() / mainvideo.height();
            mainvideo.css('height', mainmenu.height() + 'px');
            mainvideo.css('width', (mainvideo.width() * scale) + 'px');
            if (mainvideo.width() > mainmenu.width()) {
                trim = (mainvideo.width() - mainmenu.width()) / 2;
                mainvideo.css('left', -trim + 'px');
            }
        } else {
            // Делаем по всей ширине
            scale = mainmenu.width() / mainvideo.width();
            mainvideo.css('width', mainmenu.width() + 'px');
            mainvideo.css('height', (mainvideo.height() * scale) + 'px');
            if (mainvideo.height() > mainmenu.height()) {
                trim = (mainvideo.height() - mainmenu.height()) / 2;
                mainvideo.css('top', -trim + 'px');
            }
        }
    }
}

window_resize();
$(window).resize(window_resize);
```

В атрибуте **style** ему задана правильная ширина, но само видео почему-то по ней не растянулось. Только после ресайза окна растягивается

Comment: $( document ).ready(window_resize);
$( window ).resize(window_resize);

Comment: @MishaSaidov Не сработало

Answer (score 1):

Зачем это делать с помощью javascript? Достаточно CSS. Например, как это реализовано на [Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.4.0-dev/less/responsive-embed.less)
Т. е. 
HTML

```
<div class="embedvideo">
    <video muted autoplay loop class="video" id="mainvideo"><source src="/assets/video/bg.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.embedvideo {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0px;
    width: 100vw;
    padding-bottom: 100vh;
}
.embedvideo .video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Для video ещё можно добавить

```
video {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Добрый. Могу предположить, что в момент, когда выполняется функция window_resize, видео не успевает загружаться. Поэтому могут возникнуть какие-то проблемы с переменной scale. Вам надо повесить событие на загрузку видео и, как только оно сработает, вызывать window_resize.